# Edit behaviour of DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, datagridtextcolumn

my `DataGrid` has a few `DataGridTemplateColumn`'s like this:

```
 <local:DataGridSyntaxColumn MinWidth="100" x:Name="cVariantNew1" Width="250">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:SyntaxTextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" SyntaxType="VARIANT" Value="{Binding Variants[0].Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Variants[0].Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"  Style="{StaticResource GridTextBox}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</local:DataGridSyntaxColumn>
```

The `DataGridSyntaxColumn` ist just to set the focus:

```
 public class DataGridSyntaxColumn : DataGridTemplateColumn
    {
        protected override object PrepareCellForEdit(FrameworkElement editingElement,
                                                RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)
        {
            editingElement.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
            return base.PrepareCellForEdit(editingElement, editingEventArgs);
        }
    }
```

This is working fine, but the editing mode does not behave like the usual `DataGridTextColumn`

For example:

- In `DataGridTextColumn` a doubleclick sets the cursor to the clicked position or if clicked in white space it selects the full content of the cell
- Start typing does not enter edit mode

Is there a way to achieve the exact same behaviour?

Comment: Did you try to inherit from DataGridTextColumn and simply override the GenerateElement method?

Comment: what is the GenerateElement method?
I need the SyntaxTextBlock to display SyntaxHighlighting

Comment: Please refer to my answer. Inherit your DataGridSyntaxColumn class from DataGridTextColumn instead of DataGridTemplateColumn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to inherit from `DataGridTextColumn` and simply override the `GenerateElement` method:

```
public class DataGridSyntaxColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        SyntaxTextBlock textBlock = new SyntaxTextBlock()
        {
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
            SyntaxType = VARIANT
        };

        BindingBase binding = Binding;
        if (binding != null)
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
        else
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty);

        return textBlock;
    }
}
```

---

```
<local:DataGridSyntaxColumn MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Variants[0].Name}"  Width="250" />
```